# Помогите с исчезновением элемента при прокрутке, пожалуйста:)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Ребята, всем привет, задача заключается в том, чтобы текст с кнопкой оставался неподвижным, а фон прокручивался (при `position: fixed` все ломается). Далее при прокрутке страницы текст и кнопка плавно исчезают, а когда я поднимаюсь снова, срабатывает анимация на элементах, как при загрузке страницы.

```js
//ПЫТАЛСЯ ЧТОТО НАПИСАТЬ, НО В ИТОГЕ НЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ(
<script type="text/javascript">
 var topBlock = $('.flexslider');
 var elementWidth = topBlock.width();
   var body = $('body');
   var bodyHeight = body.outerHeight(true);
 var scrolledBlock = $('.todo');
 var sbWidth = scrolledBlock.width();
 var winHeight = $(window).height();
 var maxScroll = bodyHeight - winHeight;
 var coeff = maxScroll/(sbWidth-elementWidth);
 
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var move = scrollTop / coeff;
        element['fade' + (scrollTop > 200 ? 'In' : 'Out')](500);
        element.css('marginLeft', move);
 });
</script>
```

```css
/*ОТМЕНА БРАУЗЕРНЫХ СТИЛЕЙ*/
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration:none;
}
li{
 list-style:none;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{

    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.1;

}
/*КОНЕЦ ОТМЕНЫ БРАУЗЕРНЫХ СТИЛЕЙ*/

/*ДЕФОЛТНЫЕ СТИЛИ*/
html,body,#main-wrapper,#wrapper-home{
 height:5000px;
 line-height:2;
}
#main-wrapper,#wrapper-home{
 height:100vh;
}
#wrapper-home h1,#wrapper-home h2,.elegant-btn{
 text-align:center;
}

/*ДЕФОЛТНЫЕ СТИЛИ КОНЕЦ*/

/*ПЕРВЫЙ БЛОК */
#wrapper-home{background:#29435E; }
#wrapper-home h1{font-style: italic;}
#wrapper-home h1,#wrapper-home h2  {
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-size: 300px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#wrapper-home h2{
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height:2em;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-top:20px;

    
}

#wrapper-home h2 a {color: #E8722C;}
.container-text{padding-top:5%; }
.elegant-btn{
 display:block;
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
 font-weight:700;
 letter-spacing:2px;
 display:block;
 width:300px;
 height:70px;
 line-height:70px;
 font-size:17px;
 border-radius: 3em;
   border: 2px solid #18A15E;
   color: white;
   margin:70px auto;
   transition: .1s ease;
   color:#18A15E;
    
  }
  .elegant-btn:hover{
   color:white;
   background-color:#18A15E;
  }


/*ПЕРВЫЙ БЛОК КОНЕЦ*/
/*анимация*/

.animate {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.waitBeforeAnim{
    -webkit-animation-delay: .25s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .25s;
    -o-animation-delay: .25s;
    animation-delay: .25s;
}

.animate.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.goUpMin {
  -webkit-animation-name: goUpMin;
  animation-name: goUpMin;
}

@-webkit-keyframes goUpMin {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.effectLoading{
    -webkit-animation-name: effectLoading;
  animation-name: effectLoading;
}

@-webkit-keyframes effectLoading {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    /*transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);*/

  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Fiber - заказать волокно</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="description" content="Здесь Вы можете заказать оптом любые виды мильтифиламентных нитей, различных волокон таких как microarm, poliarm от торговой марки 'Fiber'. " />
 <meta name="keywords" content="волокно, fiber, microarm, poliarm, нити, мультифиламентные, заказать, оптом, microarm" />
 <meta name="author" content="vk.com/morafonskiy" />
   <!-- Facebook and Twitter integration -->
 <meta property="og:title" content=""/>
 <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
 <meta property="og:url" content=""/>
 <meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
 <meta property="og:description" content=""/>
 <meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
 <meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
 <meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
 <meta name="twitter:card" content="" />
 <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,400italic,700italic|Merriweather:300,400italic,300italic,400,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <!-- Animate.css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/MyAnimate.css">
 <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/icomoon.css">
 <!-- Simple Line Icons -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/simple-line-icons.css">
 <!-- Datetimepicker -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
 <!-- Flexslider -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/flexslider.css">
 <!-- Jquery -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap  -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <!-- Главный файл со стилями  -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
 <!-- Modernizr JS -->
 <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
 <!-- FOR IE9 below -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <!-- Чтобы изменить иконку поместите favicon.ico в папку images -->
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700,400italic,700italic|Merriweather:300,400italic,300italic,400,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Roboto+Slab:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main-wrapper">
   <div id="wrapper-home" class="fullheight" data-section="home">
    <div class="flexslider">
    <div class="parallax">
     <div class="container-text">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row" id="todo">
        <h1 class="animate goUpMin">Fiber</h1>
        <h2 class="animate waitBeforeAnim goUpMin">сотрудничай только <span>с</span> <a href="#about">профессионалами</a></h2>
        <a href="#callback" class="elegant-btn animate effectLoading">CВЯЗАТЬСЯ</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     </div>
<!--        <ul class="slides">
        <li style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1E3D7E, #6DAADC);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></li>
        <li style="background: linear-gradient(to top left, #1E3D7E, #6DAADC);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></li>
        <li style="background: linear-gradient(to top left, #1E3D7E, #6DAADC);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"></li>
       </ul> -->
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>

 </body>
```

Comment: `element` это что?

Comment: в моем джс файле что я писал все неправильно(

Comment: Так, что ли надо? )) http://lepimivarim.kagg.eu/menu/